# Linux, su, disable fingerprint auth on remote sessions

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, fingerprint

I've a fingerprint reader on my laptop and I installed fprintd to connect using it.
That works very well but there is this problem : When I remote connect to my laptop then I do a su/sudo command, I'm asking to swipe my finger. It works if I'm near the computer... but I'd prefer to disable it for cases I'm distant. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Not solving your problem but don't use fingerprints for authentification because [they are easily stolen](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/03/30/german_interior_minister_fingerprint_appropriated/) and always with you ([wrench decryption](http://xkcd.com/538/) is much easier if one has just to push your finger on the scanner). And btw [touch id was hacked](http://www.ccc.de/en/updates/2013/ccc-breaks-apple-touchid) by fingerprints on the iphone display so you are basically printing your password all over your laptop... (Also why do you need to ssh into your laptop?)

Comment: yeah I agree :D
but I've no critical informations on this laptop, i use it 1) for fun 2) impress university mates 3) 1s faster than type my password.
for the ssh access, it's for some network test and take control of my computer remotely (and some time, I don't have it but need an access without giving my password, so it's easier to connect to internet...)

Comment: then this question has never been asked thus...

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug filed for that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/776779) in ubuntu which does not seem to have been resolved yet. That suggest there is no native way in `fprint` to do that. The workaround suggested by one user in there is to wait for the timeout.

From what I see pam can be configured in a certain way to fall back to password in case no print can be read by `fprint`. [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint) says

```
auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth      include   system-login
```

in `/etc/pam.d/system-local-login` not sure if that applies for your system too (for good measure [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-912114-start-0.html) is someone configuring it in gentoo).So you should be able to allow pam to fall back on password with the right configuration.

*I want to reiterate my comment for users that still don't know: Fingerprints (or biometrics in general) are not secure means of authentication (as the simpelest of the many flaws: you leave them all over your computer when you touch it).*

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

- Start two remote sessions.
- On the first one, perform a `sudo pwd`. This will fire the fingerprint.
- On the second, perform your desired command: `sudo apt-get upgrade`(or whatever). Since the fingerprint is blocked by the first session, it will skip directly to password authentication. No timeout.